# Python flask : No module named requests

Tags: python, flask

I'm having trouble using `requests` module in my flask app. I have two files `rest_server.py` and `independent.py` at same directory level. The `independent.py` uses `requests` module and it executes correctly if I directly run it. But when I import `independent.py` in `rest_server.py` it shows following error
`

```
import independent
  File "/home/satwik/Desktop/angelhack/independent.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests`
```

I've tried `pip install requests` and it shows requirement already satisfied. Also I've tried to import `requests` in `rest_server.py` and found it to execute correctly too. 
Here's my code

**independent.py **

```
`import json
import os
import sys
import requests
sys.path.append('/home/satwik/Desktop/angelhack/comprehensive_search')
```

** rest_server.py **

```
`#!flask/bin/python
import six
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
import independent

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")`
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

## Why you get the "no module named ..." error

Your two files have one big difference: rest_server.py includes a *shebang* line, while independent.py doesn't.

When you say you *directly execute* the file `independent.py`, you type `python independent.py` (I'm assuming here, because you didn't specify that). That means you are executing with the system python interpreter, which will look for modules installed at system level. Systemwide you have the *requests* module installed, via `pip install requests`, so python finds it, imports the thing and happily runs your script.

When you execute the file `rest_server.py`, instead, you can do so calling the script's name: `./rest_server.py` (assuming correct permissions settings). In this case, the first line `#!flask/bin/python` (the so called *shebang line*) instructs to use a different python interpreter, the one contained in the `flask` folder, which I assume contains a virtual environment.

You get the `no module named requests` because **that module is not installed inside the *flask* virtual environment**.

## How you can fix the error

To fix the problem, just **install the *requests* module inside the virtual environment**.

You first activate the virtual environment and then install the module you need:

```
$ source flask/bin/activate
$ pip install requests
```

Then you can try execute `./rest_server.py` again and the *requests* module should be properly imported.

For more on the shebang line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

For more on virtual environments: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do `pip install <package>`, it installs the package to a certain location. Add that location to the list of `PATH`s mentioned in your `Environment Variables`, and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

hi i had same problem but i solved it :

after you activate venv env by this command `. venv/bin/activate`
in this env u can type `pip install requests`

or

in ur project directory u can open pyvenv.cfg and turn

`include-system-site-packages = false`

to

`include-system-site-packages = true`

:)